Calling component in a Cell using CakePHP 4
How is a component called in a cell? Or is that still not advisable? Ex. CakePHP 3 Component in a Cell
I have the following code in my cell:
$coordinatorDiscussions->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    return $results->map(function ($row) {  
        $row['formatted'] = $this->Global->formatDiscussion($row['created'], $row['user_name'],$row['comments']);
        return $row;            
    });            
});

Cell usage seemed to be appropriate for my use case. My main table has a foreign key with one-to-many possibilities that require a UI to be rendered for each (some, quite convoluted).
I was hoping to do something like this, instead of adding all that logic in one controller action:
<?php
//pseudo-code
foreach($fk as $fk_id)
{
    switch($fk_id)
    {
        case 1: echo $this->cell('Fk1Cell::ui'); break;
        case 2: echo $this->cell('Fk2Cell::ui'); break;
        case n: echo $this->cell('FkNCell::ui'); break;
    }
}
?>


It's your formatDiscussion function that's in the component? Is there anything stopping you from moving that to another class, not a component?

@GregSchmidt I was attempting to avoiding duplication. It's currently being used in Controllers which call the Component. Do you have more details on being able to instantiate a class throughout a CakePHP app?

CakePHP is, at the end of the day, just PHP, so use standard PHP namespacing and file naming techniques to create a class anywhere you want. For example, create a file called src/Service/Discussion.php, put a class called Discussion in the App\Service namespace in it, then use App\Service\Discussion; and $discussion = new Discussion(); wherever you need it.
